# Drupal Accordion

Tags: drupal, view, accordion

Where can I find a good tutorial about Accordion for Drupal. I want to make a Horizontal Accordion that uses Views. Something like this:
http://christeningcards.net/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you know about [Views Accordion](http://drupal.org/project/views_accordion) and [its documentation](http://drupal.org/node/366263), but it also looks like the horizontal accordion is not a feature? At least not according to http://drupal.org/node/1010842